# А criterion for the existence of a transformation of a set of points under which the ordering of point pairs based on distances in pairs reverses

Tags: mg.metric-geometry

More formally, I'm looking for a criterion that should be satisfied by a finite set of planar points $A$ in order for the following condition to be fulfilled: it exists a map $f:A \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{2}$
$$
\begin{split}
\rho (x, y) &\leq \rho (u, v) \\
&\Downarrow\\
\rho(f(x), f(y)) &\geq \rho(f(u), f(v))
\end{split} 
\begin{split}
\forall x, y, u, v & \in A,\\
u \neq v \;&\wedge\; x\neq y
\end{split}
$$
I would also know if there exists an algorithm that determines whether such transform $f$ exists in a finite time (and ideally provide such an $f$).

Obviously such $f$ exist if $|A| = 3$. If $A:|A|=4$ and all distances are different there exists an algorithm such that its finiteness proves the existence of $f$ for any such A([code](https://pastebin.com/bMCrPZka)). Unfortunately, the criterion and the deterministic algorithm for large A are unknown to me and I would like you to find any of them.